# How to Taylor Series expand $f(x + g(x))$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Say I want to Taylor expand $f(x)$ about $x$ for small perturbations $dx$. This is straightforward

$$f(x + dx) = f(x) + f'(x) \, dx + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)(dx)^2 + \cdots$$

However, what if my perturbation is itself a function of $x$? For example,

$$f(x + g(x)) = \text{?}$$

Does this case need any special treatment? Also, any references that would help give me a deeper understanding of Taylor series is appreciated.

Comment: The derivative of $f(x+g(x))$ is $f'(x+g(x))(1+g'(x))$.  And it gets twice as complicated with each derivative thereafter.

Comment: There is an alternative way, if you recall that the taylor polynomial of the composition of functions is the composition of their taylor polynomials